# Form action not getting the data

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I can't get the value of the check box field. This is the structure of my code

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>Home/dashboard" method="post">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="delete" onclick="cliked1(event)"  
style="margin-left:2px;background-color:blue;color:white;">Delete Item</button>
 <td><input  class="checkbox"  type="checkbox"name="cb" value="1"> 1 </td>
</form>
```

In the controller

```
else if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  $cb = $this->input->post('cb');
  echo $cb;
}
```

I recreated the process it in other file and it works

```
<form action ="<?php echo base_url()?>Shop/test" method="POST">
  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="lol">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="yeaa"> 
</form>
```

In the Controller

```
    function test()
    {
        $this->load->view('test');
        if(isset($_POST['delete']))
        {
            $id = implode('^',$this->input->post('cb'));
            print_r($id);
        }
    }
```

And I apply this process and it turns like this

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Item Photo</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Stocks</th>
        <th>Date Posted</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <form action ="<?php echo base_url()?>Shop/test" method="POST">
        <?php
        $x=1;

        foreach($shop_items as $key)
        {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><input class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="<?php $key->shop_item_id?>"> <?php echo $x;?> </td>
            <td><center><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/items_main/<?php echo $key->shop_item_main_pic;?>"  style = "width:60px;height:50px;"alt=""></center></td>
            <td><?php echo mb_strimwidth($key->shop_item_name, 0, 18,"...");?></td>
            <td style="width:10px;"><center><button><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></button></center></td>
            <td><?php echo date('F,d,Y',strtotime($key->shop_item_date_posted))?></td>
            <td><?php if(!$key->shop_item_sale){ echo number_format($key->shop_item_orig_price);}
            else{ echo "<font color='red'>".number_format(intval($key->shop_item_orig_price-($key->shop_item_orig_price*($key->shop_item_sale/100))))."</font> ";}?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="">Bid </a> | <a href=""> View</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $x+=1; 
        }
        ?>
    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>

    </form>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

The problem is that the submit button does not work.

Comment: If the checkbox is not checked you cannot get the value.

Comment: in your line <?php echo base_url(); ?>  there is a missing semicolon....check that

Comment: @pritesh That's not a problem man.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a checkbox, when the checkbox is not checked, you will not get the checkbox set in the `$_POST`. So to get the value of checkbox, you need to do this:

```
if (isset($_POST["cb"])) {
  // Checkbox is checked.
  $cb = $_POST["cb"];
} else {
  // Checkbox is not checked.
}
```

And please do not check on `type="submit"`.

From one of the [resources](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?562749-PHP-Checking-if-a-form-has-been-submitted-the-correct-way):

> In most cases this will work, but there are a few occasions when it won't. To identify when this condition will fail we have to look at the different ways of submitting a form.
>
> There are two ways of submitting a form, one is to click the submit button, the other is to hit return, of which will invoke the submit button. The problem occurs when you hit the return button (as most people do), when using Internet Explorer (the most commonly used browser) and when the submit button does not have focus. This will submit the form, but it will **not send** the `submit` variable, which would mean the script we are using above will fail.

Comment: if I do not use isset on ($_POST['delete']) there will be an error of Undefined index: delete . Is this is what you mean ?

Comment: @JonasDulay Don't use the `$_POST["delete"]` at all completely. Tell me actually what you wanna do, I will give you a better solution.

Comment: I am using tabs wherein there are different forms. In this tab I have too many action like featured the checked items, delete the checked items and etc.

Comment: @JonasDulay What does the `onclick` does then?

Comment: Just a confirmation if the user want to proceed the action. I have tried to recreate it on other file and it works . That is why I am asking here why it does not work anymore.

Comment: `recreate it on other file and it works` - What's the difference in this file from that one?

Comment: <form action ="<?php echo base_url()?>Shop/test" method="POST">
  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="lol">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="yeaa"> 
</form>

Comment: if(isset($_POST['delete']))
   {
    $id = implode('^',$this->input->post('cb'));
    print_r($id);
   }

Comment: @JonasDulay Can you even understand what you posted?

Comment: I don't know how can I tell it to you with a proper format... I will post it on the my question above

Comment: @JonasDulay Yes please.